# On the foliation determined by isometric flow on homogeneous manifold

Tags: differential-topology, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a non-compact homogeneous, 1-connected Riemannian manifold with $G := Isom(M,g)$ and let $v \in \Gamma (M,TM)$ be a $G$-invariant, nowhere-vashining vector field, such that $||v|| = 1$ everywhere. Then $v$ determines a global flow $\phi_v: \mathbb R \times M \to M$ such that at each time $t \in \mathbb R$, $\phi_v^t := \phi_v(t, \; \_  \;)$ commutes with every element $g \in G$

The trajectories of $\phi_v$ form the leaves of a $1$-dimensional foliation $\mathfrak F$ of $M$. Now suppose further that for each $t \in \mathbb R$, we have that $\phi_v^t \in G$. Now I have the following questions:

1) Is $\mathfrak F$ always a regular foliation? (in other words, are the trajectories embedded submanifolds ?)

2) If so, does $Y :=M/ \mathfrak F$ always have the structure of a smooth manifold, such that the quotient map is a submersion

3) For $F \in \mathfrak F$ a leaf, is $F \hookrightarrow M \rightarrow Y $ always a fiber bundle ? (In particular, are all leaves diffeomorphic? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the 3-dimensional round sphere and its isometry group $O(4)$. This group contains the subgroup $U(2)$, whose center is isomorphic to $U(1)$ (scalar unitary matrices). Of course, $O(4)\ne U(2)$, but one can modify the constant curvature metric on $S^3$ making it a *Berger sphere* $B=S^3_{t,\epsilon}$, whose isometry group (for generic values of $\epsilon, t$) is $U(2)$, see [this paper](http://digital.csic.es/bitstream/10261/15738/1/BergerGO.PDF):

P.Gadea and J.Oubina, Homogeneous Riemannian Structures on
Berger 3-Spheres.

Now, take $C=B\times B$ with the product metric. Except for the $Z_2$-symmetry (swapping the factors), which one can eliminate by, say, rescaling the metric on one of the factors, the isometry group of $C$ is $U(2)\times U(2)$, hence, its center is the torus $T^2=S^1\times S^1$. The manifold  $C$ is homeogeneous, simply-connected and compact. But $T^2$ contains a subgroup $H$ isomorphic to ${\mathbb R}$ (actually, continuum of such subgroups, but we just need one) whose orbits are not closed (their closures are tori); the action of this subgroup yields your flow.  This is a counter-example in the setting of compact manifolds. To make a noncompact example, take $M=C\times {\mathbb R}$ with the product metric and use the same subgroup $H$ as before: The full isometry group of $M$ is $Isom({\mathbb R})\times U(2)\times U(2)$, so $H$ is still contained in its center.

Comment: Thanks for your very informative answer ! The question came up when reading through Thurston's book, more specifically his proof for the existence of at most 8 different maximal 3-dimensional geometries. In it, he assumed that (M,g) is a (homogeneous) maximal geometry, with point stabilizer isomorphic to SO(2). The vector field $v$ is then induced by collection of all tangent lines fixed by the respective stabilizers. Then he shows that the corresponding flow is by isometries and states that 1), 2) and 3) now "easily" follow. I don't quite see why...

Comment: @BerniWaterman: In dimension 3, I think, there is not enough room for examples such as mine., since you need a Lie group whose center contains $T^2$, and that's too much.